# Do I have to return a pointer from a factory?

Tags: c++, c++11, factory, rvalue-reference

Can anyone see any problems with returning an object by value from a factory rather than returning a unique_ptr?

The following compiles and runs correctly for me, but i'm unsure if i've missed something about l-value and r-value reference interactions and lifetimes.

I've the following class hierarchy,

```
#include <iostream>

struct Reader {
    virtual ~Reader() {}
    virtual void get(int& val) = 0;
};

struct CinReader : public Reader {
    ~CinReader() { std::cout << "~CinReader()\n"; }

    void get(int& val) override
    {
        std::cout << "CinReader::get\n";
        std::cin >> val;
    }
};

struct ConstantReader : public Reader {
    void get(int& val) override
    {
        std::cout << "ConstantReader::get\n";
        val = 120;
    }
};
```

I am using the following factory to return instances,

```
enum class ReaderType { cin = 0, constant = 1 };

Reader&& readerFactoryObj(ReaderType type)
{
    switch (type) {
    case ReaderType::cin:
        return std::move(CinReader());
        break;
    case ReaderType::constant:
        return std::move(ConstantReader());
        break;
    default:
        throw "Unknown Reader type";
    }
}
```

and used as follows,

```
int main(void)
{
    auto&& reader = readerFactoryObj(ReaderType::cin);
    int val;
    reader.get(val);
}
```

It works when passed to something that stores a reference to the `Reader` interface,

```
class Doubler
{
public:
    Doubler(Reader& reader) : mReader(reader) { }

    void doubleNum() const;

private:
    Reader& mReader;
};

void Doubler::doubleNum() const
{
    int val;
    mReader.get(val);
    std::cout << val * 2 << '\n';
}

int main(void)
{
    auto&& reader = readerFactoryObj(ReaderType::cin);
    Doubler d(reader);
    d.doubleNum();
}
```

I realise `reader` isn't of type `Reader` now, but will be one of its concrete sub-classes.

Are there any problems with passing `reader` as `Reader&` and storing it?

Update:
  I added a destructor to CinReader and it clearly shows me that its lifetime ends before it's used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're returning references to temporary objects. Undefined behavior. The compiler would likely warn you if you didn't trick it with a completely redundant `move` call.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you might return from factory-functions:

1. Pointers. Either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, not raw pointers, so ownership-semantics are explicit and RAII works.
2. The object itself by value. For an example, look at `std::make_shared`, `std::allocate_shared` and so on.

What you must never do is returning a reference or pointer to storage which will be cleaned up on return, like stack-variables.
The compiler might not catch you, it might seem to work (for a time), [but it's undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794).

In your case, returning by pointer would be the right thing, so polymorphism works.

As an aside, don't throw string-literals, throw a `std::exception` or derived.

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone see any problems with returning an object by value from a factory rather than returning a unique_ptr?

A valid question, but your factory doesn't return by value. Its return type is a reference type, so you're returning by reference.

> It works when passed to something that stores a reference to the Reader interface,

No, it only appears to work because your `Reader` types are stateless and so you happen to get away with using them after their lifetime has ended.

```
Reader&& readerFactoryObj(ReaderType type)
{
  ...
    return std::move(CinReader());
```

You are creating a temporary (which is an rvalue) then using `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue (that's completely redundant) then returning a dangling reference to that temporary. This is really really bad. Don't do that. Ever.

If you want the efficiency and simplicity of move semantics then just make your functions return by value and say `return x;`, it's easier and does the right thing, unlike doing unnecessary casts and returning dangling references, which is more complicated and wrong.

In your specific case, since your factory wants to return two different types you can't return by value or you'd [slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the object and only return the base part. So you need to return by pointer, and you had better return by smart pointer or children will point and laugh at you in the street.

Comment: Why did std::move get rid of the compiler error? If the value was already an rvalue, what difference does putting it through std::move make?

Comment: The only difference it makes is to hide what's happening from the compiler, because the compiler only spends so much effort trying to decide what it should warn you about. Although in theory the compiler could analyse `std::move` and determine it should still give you a warning, in practice what actually happens is that any form of  `return some_function(x)` prevents the "returning reference to temporary" warning because potentially `some_function` could return a valid reference to some global object.

Answer (score 2):

The design problem is that factories generally return an object of unspecified type, which *at least* implements the desired interface (base class). However, it may (and often will) return objects of a more derived class.

Returning such an object by value would cause slicing. Returning a reference causes lifetime issues (as your code demonstrates). Returning a smart pointer fixes those lifetime issues.